# Notation for aggregating differents sets and stacking vectors to consitute a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider 3 different sets: $F_a$, $F_b$ and $F_c$. Each consists of different number of matrix $m$ as elements (K, P and N, respectively). Matrices $m_i^a$, $m_i^b$ and $m_i^c$ have different dimension. In mathematical notation:

$F_a = (m_i^a)_{i=1}^K$,

$F_b = (m_i^b)_{i=1}^P$,

$F_c = (m_i^c)_{i=1}^N$,

(I didn't succeed to write brackets so I use parentheses for each set)

**First problem**: I need to aggregated these 3 sets into 1 global set $F$, then I want to obtain a mean vector $v∈\mathbb{R}^{K+P+N}$ after calculating the mean value of every matrix $m$ of $F$.

**Second problem**: the 3 sets correspond to 1 observation. To 1 observation correspond one vector $v$. However, I have 1000 observations and I need to aggregate these vectors to constitute a data matrix.

I really struggle to write the mathematical notation for both problems. Can anyone give some advice?